# upload both project jar & exernal jar to local maven repository

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

My android project structure (MyApp is a module of Android Studio project):

```
MyApp
  - external/
      mylib.jar
  - src/
  - res/
  ...
  build.gradle
```

I firstly have an external jar, and I want to upload it to my local maven repo, my gradle build looks like this:

```
configurations {
    externalJar
}

artifacts {

    externalJar file: file('external/mylib.jar')
    artifact = 'exernalLib'
    version = '1.1.0'
}

uploadExternalJar {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository")
        }
    }
}
```

It works!

Then, I would also like to upload my project jar artifact to local maven repo. I added the following code:

```
group = 'com.my.app'
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository")
            pom.project {
                version  '1.2.1'
                artifactId  'MyApp'
                packaging 'jar'
            }

        }
    }
}
```

when I run `./gradlew build` , both tasks are executed, but when I check MyApp-1.2.1.jar in local maven, its content is overrode by external lib jar.

I am not sure what I did wrong. But how could I upload both external jar & my project jar to local maven then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all but i can try to gues what just happen. 
task `uploadArchives {...}` according to gradle specification is type : `(type: Upload)`

So lets go to upload specification, and what we got here:

Properties:

- artifacts
- configuration
- repositories
- uploadDescriptor

and i guess that you have:

```
configurations {
    externalJar
}
```

above the uploadArchives as global configuration, so uploadArchives has taken your externalJar as configuration to MyApp-1.2.1.jar.

Maybe try to add empty `confirguration{}` inside `uploadArchives {}`